# I'm migrating to vue3 <script setup>, but computed doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Migrating vue2 script to vue3 <script setup>. But even if seriesData is changed, the computed function is not working

my current source is like this (it is working)

```html
<template>
    <highcharts :options="drawChart"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
        seriesData: {},
        title: '',
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.getChartData()
},
computed: {
    drawChart() {
        this.seriesData.credits = false
        this.seriesData.chart = {
            type: 'area',
            marginLeft: 130
        }
        this.seriesData.title = {
            text: this.title
        }
    ...
    return this.seriesData
    }
},
methods: {
    getChartData() {
        axios.get('url')
            .then((res) => {
                let seriesData = {
                    title: { text: ''},
                    series: [{name : res.data.name, data: []}]
                }
                ...
                this.title = res.data.title
                this.seriesData = seriesData
            })
    }
}
}
</script>
```

[result(the title is truncated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu51J.png)

and this is the migrated Vue3 script setup

```html
<script setup>
import {computed, onMounted} from "vue"

let seriesData = {}

const drawChart = computed(() => {
    seriesData.credits = false
    seriesData.chart = {
    type: 'area',
    marginLeft: 130
    }
    ...
    return seriesData
})

onMounted(() => {
    getChartData()
})

function getChartData() {
    axios.get('url')
    then((res) => {
        seriesData.series = [{ name: res.data.name, data: []}]
        seriesData.title.text = res.data.title
    })
}
</script>
<template>
    <highcharts :options="drawChart"/>
</template>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYWlO.png)

Data is displayed on the console, but no output is displayed on the screen.

Comment: You need to use `ref()` or `reactive()` so variables will be reactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I wrote in comment. Old Vue 2 `data()` function is making variables reactive inside of it. In `setup()` function, variables that need to be reactive have to be made out of `ref()` or `reactive()` function.

```html
<script setup>
import {computed, onMounted, reactive} from "vue"

const seriesData = reactive({
   credits: false,
   series: [],
   chart: {},
   title: {
      text: ''
   }
})

// Computed property should not change data it's operating on in?
// You should return compleatly diffrent value/object.
const drawChart = computed(() => {
    return { ...seriesData, credits: false, chart: { type: 'area', marginLeft: 130 } }
    // seriesData.credits = false
    // seriesData.chart = {
    // type: 'area',
    // marginLeft: 130
    // }
    // return seriesData
})

onMounted(() => {
    getChartData()
})

function getChartData() {
    axios.get('url')
    then((res) => {
        seriesData.series = [{ name: res.data.name, data: []}]
        seriesData.title.text = res.data.title
    })
}
</script>
```